# Separation of variables - validity of mathematical operators and manipulations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $\frac{dy}{5y+6}$ = $(3+2x)\,dx$. Using separation of variables, I am to find the solution and put it in the form of a function $F(x,y) =G(x) + H(y) - K = 0$

There's two ways I noticed I could do this, both of which yield answers that don't appear to be equivalent.

The first half of the work was the same for both methods:
Integrating both sides, I get the equation

$$\frac{\ln(5y+6)}{5}=3x + x^2$$

$$= \ln(5y+6) = 15x + 5x^2$$

At this point, there are two things I could do. Only one of them was correct according to the online homework portal.
Here's what I did:

**Method I:**
Simplifying further by taking the exponential on both sides,

$$5y + 6 = e^{(15x + 5x^2)}$$

And so, $-e^{(15x + 5x^2)} + 5y + 6 = 0$

**Method II**:
Don't take the exponential, but instead, simply:
$\ln(5y + 6) - 15x + 5x^2 = 0$

Apparently, only the second method is correct. I thought about it, and it is clear why they are not both identical ways of expressing the solution, because the domain for the $ln$ function in the second method is restricted since the value inside the parentheses cannot be negative.

My question is: What makes one equation 'more correct' than the other? Further, since the mathematical operations I performed for either method are valid, why would I get a domain restriction for one form of the solution and not for the other?

Comment: I think *both* way are equally wrong - you forget the integral constant.

Comment: You also missed some absolute values

Comment: To add to the comment by @Asydot, you also need to write $\log |5y+6|$.

Comment: Agreed, but that does not explain why the answer that is produced using Method I isn't being accepted.

Comment: One can indeed ask why the program likes one wrong answer better than another wrong answer.

Comment: The program actually ignores the constants (such as +6 for method one), only looks at the variables. That's why I didn't include the constant of integration in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have done two mistakes. First is missing the absolute value for the logarithm. Second is missing the constant of integration. So, I write you down the correct process which finally leads to the same results by both methods. You have

$${{dy} \over {5y + 6}} = \left( {3 + 2x} \right)dx$$
Integrate, considering what I mentioned above

$$\ln \left| {5y + 6} \right| = 3x + {x^2} + C$$

**Method I** leads to

$$\left| {5y + 6} \right| = {e^{3x + {x^2} + C}}$$

which rearranging terms leads to

$$\left| {5y + 6} \right| + K{e^{3x + {x^2}}} = 0$$

where $K =  - {e^C}$. But there is some little point, this form is not like what the question wanted since the constant appeared as the coefficient of the exponential function.

**Method 2** which is much easier, gives

$$\ln \left| {5y + 6} \right| - (3x + {x^2}) - C = 0$$

which is exactly like the form question wants.